# Regular expression for highlighting numbers between words

Tags: php, regex

Site users enter numbers in different ways, example:

```
from 8 000 packs
432534534
from 344454 packs
45054 packs
04 555
434654
54 564 packs
```

I am looking for a regular expression with which I could highlight words before digits (if there are any), digits in any format and words after (if there are any). It is advisable to exclude spaces.

Now I have such a design, but it does not work correctly.

```
(^[0-9|a-zA-Z].*?)\s([0-9].*?)\s([a-zA-Z]*$)
```

The main purpose of this is to put the strings in order, bring them to the same form, format them in PHP digit format, etc.

As a result, I need to get the text before the digits, the digits themselves and the text after them into the variables separately.

```
$before = 'from';
$num    = '8000';
$after  = 'packs';
```

Thank you for any help in this matter)

Comment: What is the actual output you want?

Comment: It may make more sense to run 2 or 3 regex instead. It would make for 3 concise regular expressions and you can handle them each individually. (1: before, 2: after, 3: before and after). If your formatting handles the ordering, then you could use 2 regex (before and after) .

Comment: Thanks. Supplemented the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may try this:

```
^(\D+)?([\d \t]+)(\D+)?$
```

1. **group 1**: optional(?) group that will contain anything but digit
2. **group 2**: mandatory group that will contain only digits and
   white space character like space and tab
3. **group 3**: optional(?) group that will contain anything but digit

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/18UCE5/1)

Source ([run](https://ideone.com/NQT4j2))

```
$re = '/^(\D+)?([\d \t]+)(\D+)?$/m';
$str = 'from 8 000 packs
432534534
from 344454 packs
45054 packs
04 555
434654
54 564 packs
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $matchgroup) 
{
    echo "before: ".$matchgroup[1]."\n";
    echo "number:".preg_replace('/\D/m','',$matchgroup[2])."\n";
    echo "after:".$matchgroup[3]."";
    echo "\n\n\n";
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your regex and added groups, the regex looks like this:

```
^(?<before>[a-zA-Z]+)?\s?(?<number>[0-9].*?)\s?(?<after>[a-zA-Z]+)?$`
```

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/QLEC9g/2

By using groups you can easily separate the words and numbers, and handle them any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match because there are 4 required parts that all expect 1 character to be present:

```
(^[0-9|a-zA-Z].*?)\s([0-9].*?)\s([a-zA-Z]*$)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^ ^^^^^    ^^
```

The other thing to note is that the first character class `[0-9|a-zA-Z]` can also match digits (you can omit the `|` as it would match a literal pipe char)

---

If you would allow all other chars than digits on the left and right, and there should be at least a single digit present, you can use a negated character class `[^\d\r\n]*` optionally matching any character except a digit or a newline:

```
^([^\d\r\n]*)\h*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)\h*([^\d\r\n]*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\d\r\n]*)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a digit or a newline
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching spaces and 1+ digits
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `([^\d\r\n]*)` Capture **group 3**, match any char except a digit or a newline
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sXkCb4/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/D4QCq).

For example

```
$re = '/^([^\d\r\n]*)\h*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)\h*([^\d\r\n]*)$/m';
$str = 'from 8 000 packs
test from 8 000 packs test
432534534
from 344454 packs
45054 packs
04 555
434654
54 564 packs';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    list(,$before, $num, $after) = $match;
    echo sprintf(
        "before: %s\nnum:%s\nafter:%s\n--------------------\n",
        $before, preg_replace("/\h+/", "", $num), $after
    );
}
```

Output

```
before: from 
num:8000
after:packs
--------------------
before: test from 
num:8000
after:packs test
--------------------
before: 
num:432534534
after:
--------------------
before: from 
num:344454
after:packs
--------------------
before: 
num:45054
after:packs
--------------------
before: 
num:04555
after:
--------------------
before: 
num:434654
after:
--------------------
before: 
num:54564
after:packs
--------------------
```

If there should be at least a single digit present, and the only allowed characters are a-z for the word(s), you can use a case insensitive pattern:

```
(?i)^((?:[a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*)?)\h*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)\h*((?:[a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*)?)?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DZNdf/1) and a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/43flW).